# Changing font color in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Here's my javascript code:

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}
```

I just want to change the color of the message "password do not match" into red.
I'm a beginner, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:

```js
password = '123x';
confirmPassword = '123';
if (password != confirmPassword) {
  $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!").css('color', '#900');

} else {
  $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.").css('color', '#090');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the message "password match" not appearing anymore

Comment: oh my bad i tried it again and it work i just found error sorry
thanks again !

Comment: No problem.. have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
```

to

```
$("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<span style='color:red'>Passwords do not match!</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (password != confirmPassword){
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<span style='color:red'>Passwords do not match!</span>");
 }   else {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css('color', 'red');`

In your 1.if ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can the css() method:

```
if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css('color', 'red');
} else {
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css('color', 'green');
}
```

More details you can find on [jquery .css documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Aye! Aye! Thanks sir/maam

Answer (score 0):

Different approach if you don't want to use jquery.

```
thePasswordTextEle = document.createElement("span")

if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    thePasswordTextEle.classList.add("red-text")
    thePasswordTextEle.innerHTML = "Password ***"
} else {
    thePasswordTextEle.classList.add("green-text")
    thePasswordTextEle.innerHTML = "Password ***"
}
document.querySelector('#divCheckPasswordMatch').innerHTML = thePasswordTextEle.outerHTML
```